# Divide IPv4 network into subnets in a SPECIFIC order

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

My private addresses start at `10.10.0.0/16`. I must make 2 subnets with 120 and 450 starting with the 120 one and not leaving any unnecessarily unused addresses.

Let me remark, it's **IMPERATIVE** that the 120 subnet goes first.

The first one (120) easily goes from `10.10.0.0/25` to `10.10.0.127/25.`

However, I'm not sure on what to do with the second subnet (450).

**Option A:** from `10.10.0.128/23` to `10.10.2.127/23`

**Option B:** from `10.10.1.0/23` to `10.10.2.255/23`

**B** leaves a huge gap from `10.10.0.128` to `10.10.0.255` but I'm not sure I can use option **A** because the only example I have seen goes for **B**.

Comment: That is explained in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499).

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.